# How to migrate asp.net core authentication to new Google SignIn service?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, google-api

I've got a message from Google that I must migrate Google+ authentication to Google SignIn for my web-site. Google+ Sign-In is deprecated and will be off at March 2019. I could not find any information how to use new Google SignIn as authentication for asp.net core.

Microsoft provides this manual
https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/aspnet/core/security/authentication/social/google-logins?view=aspnetcore-2.2
But this is deprecated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For now I have following solution and it works.

```
  services.AddAuthentication().AddGoogle(googleOptions =>  
    {  
        googleOptions.ClientId = Configuration["Authentication:Google:ClientId"];  
        googleOptions.ClientSecret = Configuration["Authentication:Google:ClientSecret"];
        googleOptions.UserInformationEndpoint = "https://openidconnect.googleapis.com/v1/userinfo";
        googleOptions.ClaimActions.Clear();
        googleOptions.ClaimActions.MapJsonKey(ClaimTypes.Name, "email");
        googleOptions.ClaimActions.MapJsonKey(ClaimTypes.GivenName, "given_Name");
        googleOptions.ClaimActions.MapJsonKey(ClaimTypes.Surname, "family_Name");
        googleOptions.ClaimActions.MapJsonKey("urn:google:profile", "profile");
        googleOptions.ClaimActions.MapJsonKey(ClaimTypes.Email, "email");
        googleOptions.ClaimActions.MapJsonKey("urn:google:image", "picture");
        googleOptions.ClaimActions.MapJsonKey(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, "sub");
    });
```

You can write googleOptions.ClaimActions.MapJsonKey(ClaimTypes.Name, "name"); 
if you want use real name as name.

Answer (score 0):

The ASP.NET Core team is [aware](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/issues/6069) of this issue. I think we just have to wait for a solution from their side, or a third-party package.

I hope they will be able to push an update to the framework, because Google is one of the default OAuth providers in .NET Core.